# Please thaw the Sandbox

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

The [chat Sandbox](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3404628#3404628) has been frozen for inactivity. This is most annoying because we can't send people there to play with the system without annoying everyone else in some other room. In other words, this disrupts the general procrastination routine of people in chat, and runs the risk of them leaving to do something else, perhaps even *gasp* do some work. This is unacceptable.

I thought about creating a new Sandbox, but it's better if some higher power can thaw it.

Comment: There... Now get to work. :P

Comment: There's also a [Sandbox](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) on [chat.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) that tends to get more activity

Answer (score 8):

Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand... done.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaanks.